# NAO Speech Recognition Problems

Tags: java, speech-recognition, speech

My students and I are working with the NAO robot.  We are having issues with the speech recognition in Java.  We can get the robot to identify words from our specified vocabulary only after the word has been spoken twice.  Thank you and please see the code below for an example:

```
public class SpeechRecog {

private static String NAOQI_IP = "10.0.1.236";
//public static String NAOQI_IP = "127.0.0.1";
private static int NAOQI_PORT = 9559;

static ALMemoryProxy memory = new ALMemoryProxy(NAOQI_IP, NAOQI_PORT);
static ALSpeechRecognitionProxy recog = new ALSpeechRecognitionProxy(NAOQI_IP, NAOQI_PORT);
static ALTextToSpeechProxy tts = new ALTextToSpeechProxy(NAOQI_IP, NAOQI_PORT);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] vocab = {"nao", "monkey", "hello"};
    recog.unsubscribe("WordRecognized");

    recog.setAudioExpression(true);
    recog.setVisualExpression(true);
    recog.setVocabulary(vocab, true);
    recog.subscribe("WordRecognized");

    while(true){
        if(memory.getData("SpeechDetected").toBoolean()){
            Variant words = memory.getData("WordRecognized");
            String word = (String)words.getElement(0).toString();
            System.out.println("The word is:" + word+":");
            float percent = (float) words.getElement(1).toFloat();
            for(int i = 0; i<words.getSize(); i+=2){
                System.out.println("Word: " + (String)words.getElement(i).toString());
                System.out.println("Probability: " + (float)words.getElement(i+1).toFloat());
            }
            //if(wordCheck())
                //break;
            if(!word.equals("") && percent > 0.2){
                if(word.equals("nao")){
                    tts.say("How can I help you?");
                    System.out.println("how?");
                    break;
                }
                else if(word.equals("monkey")){
                    System.out.println("who you calling");
                    tts.say("who you callin a monkey?");
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Not recognized");
                }
            }
        }

    } 
    recog.unsubscribe("WordRecognized");
    System.out.println("done!");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here's some hints:

1 - "SpeechDetected" is raised at the beginning of heard human voice, so it's set a few seconds before "WordRecognized" is filled (that last is filled when the human stop to speak, and after the analyse).

So it's not the good condition to enter the "read loop", as it will always be set to nothing or to the previous value.

You should just for example set WordRecognized to "" before launching the speech reco, then poll it, and when it's no more "", you've got your recognised words.

2 - don't make a loop without sleep, as you'll overload your cpu, leaving quite nothing to your speech recognition process to compute...

Answer (score 0):

Is the robot able to detect speech after the word has been spoken once i.e is the system able to tell that something has been said at all after the word has been spoken once?

Comment: From all of our tests, it does not actually store the word in the memory after it has been spoken once.  Interesting though, when we removed the following boolean the problem is resolved entirely: 

if(memory.getData("SpeechDetected").toBoolean()){  

My guess is that the SpeechDetected boolean does not do what we are expecting it to do.  The good news though, is that we have it working without it!

Comment: Great. Kindly include updated code snippet for others who might encounter similar problems